# How to use partition by in Linq query in C#, to add column values in subsequent rows?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to group my list of inventories by ProductNumber, ColorCode & SizeCode. Then I want to order it by Date And Quantity should keep adding itself to the next row.

Example, if the quantities are: 15, 10, 25, 5

Result should be: 15, 25, 50, 55

How this can be achieved using Linq?

```
List<ApiInventory> inventory = new List<ApiInventory>()
        {
            new ApiInventory() { ProductNumber = 1, ColorCode = "Blue", SizeCode = "XXL",
                AvailableDate = new DateTime(2018,9,25), AvailableQty=50 },
            new ApiInventory() { ProductNumber = 1, ColorCode = "Blue", SizeCode = "XXL",
                AvailableDate = new DateTime(2018,8,25), AvailableQty=30},
            new ApiInventory() { ProductNumber = 1, ColorCode = "Blue", SizeCode = "XXL",
                AvailableDate = new DateTime(2018,10,25), AvailableQty=60 },
            new ApiInventory() { ProductNumber = 1, ColorCode = "Blue", SizeCode = "XXL",
                AvailableDate = new DateTime(2018,7,25), AvailableQty=40},

            new ApiInventory() { ProductNumber = 2, ColorCode = "Blue", SizeCode = "XXL",
                AvailableDate = new DateTime(2018,9,25), AvailableQty=150 },
            new ApiInventory() { ProductNumber = 2, ColorCode = "Blue", SizeCode = "XXL",
                AvailableDate = new DateTime(2018,8,25), AvailableQty=300},
            new ApiInventory() { ProductNumber = 2, ColorCode = "Blue", SizeCode = "XXL",
                AvailableDate = new DateTime(2018,10,25), AvailableQty=500 },

            new ApiInventory() { ProductNumber = 1, ColorCode = "Red", SizeCode = "XXL",
                AvailableDate = new DateTime(2018,7,25), AvailableQty=330},
            new ApiInventory() { ProductNumber = 1, ColorCode = "Red", SizeCode = "XXL",
                AvailableDate = new DateTime(2018,10,25), AvailableQty=690 },
            new ApiInventory() { ProductNumber = 1, ColorCode = "Green", SizeCode = "XXL",
                AvailableDate = new DateTime(2018,9,25), AvailableQty=450}
        };

        foreach (var item in inventory)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ProductNumber + " " + item.ColorCode + " " + item.SizeCode + " "
                + item.AvailableDate + " " + item.AvailableQty);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        inventory = inventory.GroupBy(i => new { i.ProductNumber, i.ColorCode, i.SizeCode }).
            SelectMany(inv => inv.OrderBy(i=>i.AvailableDate).Select((i,q) =>  new ApiInventory
            {
                ProductNumber= i.ProductNumber,
                ColorCode = i.ColorCode,
                SizeCode = i.SizeCode,
                AvailableDate = i.AvailableDate,
                AvailableQty = i.AvailableQty + q
            })).ToList();




        foreach (var item in inventory)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ProductNumber +" " + item.ColorCode + " " + item.SizeCode + " " 
                + item.AvailableDate + " " + item.AvailableQty);
        }
```

Probable solution, but doesn't look efficient. Please suggest something better.

```
inventory = inventory.GroupBy(i => new { i.ProductNumber, i.ColorCode, i.SizeCode }).
            SelectMany(inv => inv.OrderBy(iv=>iv.AvailableDate).Select((inven) =>  new ApiInventory
            {
                ProductNumber= inven.ProductNumber,
                ColorCode = inven.ColorCode,
                SizeCode = inven.SizeCode,
                AvailableDate = inven.AvailableDate,
                AvailableQty = inven.AvailableQty + inv.Where(w=> w.AvailableDate< inven.AvailableDate)
                    .Sum(ww=>ww.AvailableQty)
            })).ToList();
```

Comment: What else Can I use? My project uses Linq, so want to keep consistency.

Comment: You do realize that because of the SelectMany you loose your groups don't you? Do you want groups or not?

Comment: not sure if you're aware that you can use SQL when dealing with complex queries https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-directly-execute-sql-queries

Comment: ur linq looks painful... please just supply the SQL and some will convert to linq for you

Answer (score 0):

Another version could be this without `GroupBy` and `SelectMany`

```
var inventory = inventory.
    OrderBy(x => x.AvailableDate).OrderBy(x => x.SizeCode).OrderBy(x => x.ProductNumber).OrderBy(x => x.ColorCode).
    Select(x => new ApiInventory
    {
        ProductNumber = x.ProductNumber,
        ColorCode = x.ColorCode,
        SizeCode = x.SizeCode,
        AvailableDate = x.AvailableDate,
        AvailableQty = inventory.Where(y => y.AvailableDate <= x.AvailableDate &&
        y.ColorCode == x.ColorCode && y.ProductNumber == x.ProductNumber && y.SizeCode == x.SizeCode
        ).Sum(z => z.AvailableQty)
    });
```

Or using statement lambda:

```
var inventory1 = inventory.
    OrderBy(x => x.AvailableDate).OrderBy(x => x.SizeCode).OrderBy(x => x.ProductNumber).OrderBy(x => x.ColorCode).
    Select(x =>
    {
        var xx = x as ApiInventory;
        xx.AvailableQty = inventory.Where(y => y.AvailableDate <= x.AvailableDate &&  
        y.ColorCode == x.ColorCode && y.ProductNumber == x.ProductNumber && y.SizeCode == x.SizeCode
        ).Sum(z => z.AvailableQty);
        return xx;
    });
```

**OutPut:**

```
1 Blue XXL 7/25/2018 12:00:00 AM 40
1 Blue XXL 8/25/2018 12:00:00 AM 70
1 Blue XXL 9/25/2018 12:00:00 AM 120
1 Blue XXL 10/25/2018 12:00:00 AM 180
2 Blue XXL 8/25/2018 12:00:00 AM 300
2 Blue XXL 9/25/2018 12:00:00 AM 450
2 Blue XXL 10/25/2018 12:00:00 AM 950
1 Green XXL 9/25/2018 12:00:00 AM 450
1 Red XXL 7/25/2018 12:00:00 AM 330
1 Red XXL 10/25/2018 12:00:00 AM 1020
```

Comment: Your OrderBy query could return strange results. it should be `OrderBy(x => x.AvailableDate).ThenBy(x => x.SizeCode).ThenBy(x => x.ProductNumber).ThenBy(x => x.ColorCode)` that way it will will always order by that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inventory2 = (from i in inventory
                 let runningTotal = inventory.Where(ix => ix.ProductNumber == i.ProductNumber && 
                    ix.ColorCode == i.ColorCode && 
                    ix.SizeCode == i.SizeCode && 
                    ix.AvailableDate <= i.AvailableDate).Sum(ix => ix.AvailableQty)
                 select new ApiInventory {
                  ProductNumber=i.ProductNumber,
                  ColorCode = i.ColorCode,
                  SizeCode = i.SizeCode,
                  AvailableDate = i.AvailableDate,
                     AvailableQty = runningTotal
                 }).OrderBy(i => i.ProductNumber)
                    .ThenBy(i => i.ColorCode)
                    .ThenBy(i => i.SizeCode)
                    .ThenBy(i => i.AvailableDate);
```